How to HOST swagger in server

I'm using spring boot project, database SQL Server 2019 and I using REST API in swagger2,version 3.0.0
I'm already run success swagger in localhost with all REST API I have
Now, I'm having some difficulty with how to HOST swagger in server

Do you guys have any ways ?

When you say host, I understand that you want to deploy the swagger documentation on the server. Would that be it?  Maybe this link can help you:
Deploy Swagger API Documentation
